# Always getting Attribute Error when using GridSearchCSV with KNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to solve a twitter sentiment analysis problem. I am using the code:

```
print()
print("Importing")
print()
#IMPORTS
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV



def getting_data(train_dataset_name, test_dataset_name):
    print()
    print("Getting the data")
    print()
    #Parameter names are self explanatory - file names for datasets
    #This assumes you are executing this code statement from inside the directory with your datasets
    train = pd.read_csv(train_dataset_name).values
    train_y = train[:,1]
    train_x = train[:,2]

    test = pd.read_csv(test_dataset_name).values
    test = test[:,1]
    test = np.reshape(test,(test.shape[0],1))

    return train_x,train_y,test



def bagOfWords(test,train_x):
    print()
    print("Creating bag of words model")
    print()
    #Creates and returns bag-of-words versions of the test and train x

    #Train transformations
    corpus_train = []
    for i in range(0,train_x.shape[0]):
        review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', train_x[i])
        review = review.lower().split()
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
        review = ' '.join(review)
        corpus_train.append(review)

    #Test transformations
    corpus_test = []
    for i in range(0,test.shape[0]):
        review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', test[i][0])
        review = review.lower().split()
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
        review = ' '.join(review)
        corpus_test.append(review)

    return corpus_train,corpus_test



def dimensionality_reduction(corpus_train,corpus_test, return_ratio, components):
    print()
    print("Performing Dimensionality Reduction")
    print()
    #CountVectorizer
    cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
    train_x = cv.fit_transform(corpus_train).toarray()

    #PCA
    pca = PCA(n_components=components)
    train_x = pca.fit_transform(train_x)
    explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_


    test = cv.transform(corpus_test).toarray()
    test = pca.transform(test)
    test = test.astype('float32')

    if (return_ratio):
        return train_x,test, explained_variance
    else:
        return train_x,test



def getOptimumParameters(train_x,train_y, return_stats):
    print()
    print("Getting optimum parameters")
    print("This optimization algorithm may take a while, so please be patient.")
    print("Please do not do other tasks while this runs.")
    print()
    train_x = train_x.astype('float32')
    train_y = train_y.astype('float32')

    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier() 
    classifier.fit(train_x,train_y)

    #For the sake of my program I used my own parameter lists.
    #If you use this code, please change them
    neighbor_list = [1,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,25]
    algorithm_list = ['brute', 'kd_tree', 'ball_tree']
    weights_list = ['uniform', 'distance']
    p_list = [1] #p_list = [1,2,3,4]
    leaf_list = [10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]
    parameters = [{'n_neighbors':neighbor_list, 'weights':weights_list, 'algorithm':algorithm_list, 'p':p_list, 'leaf_size':leaf_list}]


    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid = parameters, cv=5,refit=True, error_score=0, n_jobs = -1)
    clf = clf.fit(train_x,train_y)

    bc = clf.best_score_
    bp = clf.best_params_

    if return_stats:
        return clf, bc, bp
    else:
        return clf



def predictions(classifier, train_x, train_y, test, ratio):
    print()
    print("Making predictions")
    print()
    #Changing types to work with a classifier
    train_x= train_x.astype('float32')
    train_y = train_y.astype('float32')

    #Splitting training set into a training + dev set
    train_x,dev_x,train_y,dev_y = train_test_split(train_x,train_y,test_size = ratio, random_state=0)
    #Making predictions
    test = test.astype('float32')
    pred = classifier.predict(test)
    return pred



def convertPredToCsv(pred, csv_name):

    df = pd.DataFrame(pred)
    df.index.name = 'id'
    df.columns = ['label']

    df.to_csv("predictions.csv")




def main():
    #Retrieving the data
    train_x,train_y,test = getting_data('train.csv', 'test_tweets.csv')
    #Constructing Bag of words model
    corpus_train,corpus_test = bagOfWords(test,train_x)
    #Performing Dimensionality Reduction
    train_x,test = dimensionality_reduction(corpus_train,corpus_test,False,350)
    #Getting the optimum classifier
    classifier= getOptimumParameters(train_x,train_y, False)
    #Predicting + converting to csv
    pred = predictions(classifier, train_x, train_y, test, 0.1)
    convertPredToCsv(pred, 'predictions.csv')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Every time it comes around to the getOptimumParameters function, I get a multitude of errors. Some say AttributeError, but for most of them, I cannot find an error name. I think most of those other errors are meant to direct me to the AttributeError. I cannot figure out why this error is occurring. I know that something is wrong with my GridSearch, but I do not know if something is wrong with the parameters(which I triple checked and cannot find any problems with), or if there is some other problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj=array([[ 0.        , 30.70562651, 27.84020028, .... 38.11465899,
        25.22553572,  0.        ]]), method='argpartition', *args=(0,), **kwds={'axis': 1, 'kind': 'introselect', 'order': None})
     47     return result
     48 
     49 
     50 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
     51     try:
---> 52         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
        obj = array([[ 0.        , 30.70562651, 27.84020028, .... 38.11465899,
        25.22553572,  0.        ]])
        method = 'argpartition'
        args = (0,)
        kwds = {'axis': 1, 'kind': 'introselect', 'order': None}
     53 
     54     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have
     55     # such a method in its class.
     56 

MemoryError:
```

The data is from a problem my analyticsvidhya. Here is the link for the download of the training data - it is a dropbox link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4tagiewcuoxgkt/train.csv?dl=0

Here is the test data link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qiitwlpnkbs2c3m/test_tweets.csv?dl=0

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the error message

Comment: add the data and the full error

Comment: I added them into the question via an edit. @seralouk

Comment: I cannot access the link for the data. Can you add the file ?

Comment: I added a dropbox link for the data. Hopefully it works, fingers crossed. Thanks for being patient with me, I'm a bit new to stack overflow @seralouk

Comment: you need to also add the test.csv

Comment: The error for this code occurs before using the test.csv, but I will add the dropbox link for that too @seraloulk

Comment: @seralouk misspelled your name in previous comment, don't know if you saw the update

Comment: just now. i am going to have a look at it

Comment: @PranavE I am running the GridSearch right now. Until now, no errors. I will let you know soon

Comment: Thank you. It does take a while, so sorry. @seralouk

Comment: Do you get the error at the beginning of the Grid ?

Comment: I think so, but i don't know for sure. @seralouk - The error happens after about 2 minutes of runtime during the grid period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it has been a while, so sorry.

Just wanted to let you guys know that for long Grid Searches, it is NECESSARY, at least for Windows users, to import not

sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

but actually

sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV

The former almost always throws a memory error, while the latter works fine even on long Grid Searches.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your modules ?

It's bizarre because the following code runs without any error on my macbook:

```
print()
print("Importing")
print()
#IMPORTS
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV



def getting_data(train_dataset_name, test_dataset_name):
    print()
    print("Getting the data")
    print()
    #Parameter names are self explanatory - file names for datasets
    #This assumes you are executing this code statement from inside the directory with your datasets
    train = pd.read_csv(train_dataset_name).values
    train_y = train[:,1]
    train_x = train[:,2]

    test = pd.read_csv(test_dataset_name).values
    test = test[:,1]
    test = np.reshape(test,(test.shape[0],1))

    return train_x,train_y,test



def bagOfWords(test,train_x):
    print()
    print("Creating bag of words model")
    print()
    #Creates and returns bag-of-words versions of the test and train x

    #Train transformations
    corpus_train = []
    for i in range(0,train_x.shape[0]):
        review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', train_x[i])
        review = review.lower().split()
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
        review = ' '.join(review)
        corpus_train.append(review)

    #Test transformations
    corpus_test = []
    for i in range(0,test.shape[0]):
        review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', test[i][0])
        review = review.lower().split()
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
        review = ' '.join(review)
        corpus_test.append(review)

    return corpus_train,corpus_test



def dimensionality_reduction(corpus_train,corpus_test, return_ratio, components):
    print()
    print("Performing Dimensionality Reduction")
    print()
    #CountVectorizer
    cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
    train_x = cv.fit_transform(corpus_train).toarray()

    #PCA
    pca = PCA(n_components=components)
    train_x = pca.fit_transform(train_x)
    explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_


    test = cv.transform(corpus_test).toarray()
    test = pca.transform(test)
    test = test.astype('float32')

    if (return_ratio):
        return train_x,test, explained_variance
    else:
        return train_x,test



def getOptimumParameters(train_x,train_y, return_stats):
    print()
    print("Getting optimum parameters")
    print("This optimization algorithm may take a while, so please be patient.")
    print("Please do not do other tasks while this runs.")
    print()
    train_x = train_x.astype('float32')
    train_y = train_y.astype('float32')

    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier() 
    #classifier.fit(train_x,train_y)

    #For the sake of my program I used my own parameter lists.
    #If you use this code, please change them
    neighbor_list = [1]
    algorithm_list = ['brute', 'kd_tree', 'ball_tree']
    weights_list = ['uniform', 'distance']
    p_list = [1] #p_list = [1,2,3,4]
    leaf_list = [10]
    parameters = [{'n_neighbors':neighbor_list, 'weights':weights_list, 'algorithm':algorithm_list, 'p':p_list, 'leaf_size':leaf_list}]


    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid = parameters, cv=5,refit=True, error_score=0, n_jobs = -1)
    clf = clf.fit(train_x,train_y)

    bc = clf.best_score_
    bp = clf.best_params_

    if return_stats:
        return clf, bc, bp
    else:
        return clf



def predictions(classifier, train_x, train_y, test, ratio):
    print()
    print("Making predictions")
    print()
    #Changing types to work with a classifier
    train_x= train_x.astype('float32')
    train_y = train_y.astype('float32')

    #Splitting training set into a training + dev set
    train_x,dev_x,train_y,dev_y = train_test_split(train_x,train_y,test_size = ratio, random_state=0)
    #Making predictions
    test = test.astype('float32')
    pred = classifier.predict(test)
    return pred



def convertPredToCsv(pred, csv_name):

    df = pd.DataFrame(pred)
    df.index.name = 'id'
    df.columns = ['label']

    df.to_csv("predictions.csv")



def main():
    #Retrieving the data
    train_x,train_y,test = getting_data('train.csv', 'test_tweets.csv')
    #Constructing Bag of words model
    corpus_train,corpus_test = bagOfWords(test,train_x)
    #Performing Dimensionality Reduction
    train_x,test = dimensionality_reduction(corpus_train,corpus_test,False,350)
    #Getting the optimum classifier
    classifier= getOptimumParameters(train_x,train_y, False)
    #Predicting + converting to csv
    pred = predictions(classifier, train_x, train_y, test, 0.1)
    convertPredToCsv(pred, 'predictions.csv')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

My versions:

```
import sklearn

print(sklearn.__version__)
#0.19.1


import nltk

print(nltk.__version__)
#3.3
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your help, I will run this code, see if all my modules are updated, and get back to you. I run on Windows 64 bit OS, so I don't know why the problem is occurring. @seralouk

Comment: I am running everything on my MacBook but I think it's all about the module versions.

Comment: Interesting. I have the same sklearn and nltk versions as you - 0.19.1 and 3.3 respectively. I updated ALL other packages in pip by manually going through my list of packages and updating each one. When I ran the script again, I got the same errors. However, I noticed a phrase which I didn't see before - at the bottom of the error there is a phrase that says 'Memory Error: ' Does this help you in any way?

Comment: Oh. What is your RAM capacity ?

Comment: 16 GB RAM, Nvidia GTX 1060, i7 7700k

Comment: Mine: Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 2.7 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory: 16 GB

Comment: I also noticed that when I run the code I use 16GB of Memory. I believe it's a memory problem of your computer

Comment: So, do you have any ideas for what I should do? I'm assuming you mean that when you run the code, you get a memory error when using 16GB RAM also?

Comment: Here is my processor info : Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU, speed : 2.80GHz, 4 Core, 8 Logical Processor

Comment: No, I do not get any error but I can see that i use 16GB (the full capacity). I think it's a memory error related to your laptop. The code runs fine and it's correct

Comment: Oh well. Thank you so much for your help and patience so far. If you could do one last thing for me, could you please send me the predictions.csv file to me via a dropbox link or another method?

Comment: Actually, @seralouk, I think I might have found a fix. I am running the script right now, but I found an issue from scikit-learn where if you import GridSearch from model_selection, you get a memory error, but if you import it from grid_search, your script runs fine. I will get back to you if this error proves out to be the case in my situation. Here is the link to the issue - http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: Let me know please. I used `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV` based on the 0.19.2 version of the documentation

Comment: how long did it take for you to run it? I have been running it for almost 3 hours and it is still on the grid search part. I have now stopped it, and I will run it again in the night and tell you tomorrow.

Comment: This is insane. My model has been running for 8+ hours on all cores, and it is not yet past the GridSearchCV part. Did yours take this long or is something wrong with mine?

Comment: Wow. Right now, I am babysitting the model, by testing out different ranges of parameters and slowly refining it. The full model will probably take 10 hours to run, and I feel like it would be more efficient to babysit the model. I might even get better results.